# sometimes Callback is not happening in USB isochronous transfer

Tags: c, libusb-1.0

I am trying to receive a transport stream over a cimax usb interface on cindrella board.
 I am using libusb for accessing the device. Problem is sometimes the callback function is not getting called and it shows device detached.

Comment: If it shows the device as detached, I would start there. Do you know why it appears to be detached?

Comment: Can you post some piece of code? The piece where the callback mechanism is referred?